# Retrieving an instance using a string literal with Google Guice

Tags: java, guice

I have multiple modules with service interfaces binding to their corresponding types and I am able to get an instance by using

```
injector.getInstance(MyServiceInterface.class)
```

I would like to retrieve the instance using

```
injector.getInstance("MyServiceInterface")
```

i.e. a string literal instead of the class type

How can I achieve this ?

To elaborate my question further - I can retrieve the Class object from the string literal using a `Class.forName(literal)` call and then use it to retrieve the instance with a `injector.getInstance(clsInstance)` .

After retrieving the instance which I receive in my base service type interface I need to use reflection to invoke the method of the service object.

so Service serv = injector.getInstance(MyCustomService.class)

Now I need to invoke myCustomMethod() present in MyCustomService through reflection since this invoker is generic and is intended to work with multiple services without being aware of their actual type.

I will also need the Method interceptors configured on the service interfaces to be invoked transparently when I invoke the method on this instance reflectively.

Answer (score 1):

While I'm not certain if there's functionality for that built into Guice itself, you could try getting the relevant `Class<?>` object yourself.

Something along the lines of:

```
Class<?> myServiceInterfaceClass = Class.forName("path.to.MyServiceInterface");
injector.getInstance(myServiceInterfaceClass);
```

This does however require that the current Classloader can access that specific class, etc.

Comment: Yes I am aware of this option but would want to know if there is a solution in Guice itself

Comment: There is no solution in Guice itself.

Comment: The issue is the invoker is generic and won't receive the instance in a derived interface, rather will receive the instance as a base type. On this I need to invoke the operation through reflection. I want to know if this breaks the Guice semantics and if it will invoke the method interceptors on the service interface appropriately

Comment: @Debasish Uhm, either I don't quite see what you're talking about or this can be easily solved by just casting the `Object` returned from `getInstance` to whatever class/interface you wish to use it as.

Answer (score 1):

This can't be done within Guice... because it can't be done, period! Think about it, let's say you have two of the same class name *in different packages*. Which class would you instantiate?

So at the very least the String would have to have the fully qualified class name, e.g. instead of `Integer`, it would have `java.lang.Integer`.

---

[However, if you know which classes you want to support in advance, you can use a MapBinder.](http://google-guice.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/inject/multibindings/MapBinder.html)

Tweaking their example to match your use case:

```
public class ServiceModule extends AbstractModule {
    protected void configure() {
        MapBinder<String, MyServiceInterface> mapbinder
                = MapBinder.newMapBinder(binder(), String.class, MyServiceInterface.class);
        mapbinder.addBinding("MyServiceInterface").to(MyServiceImpl.class);

        bind(MyServiceInterface.class).to(MyServiceImpl.class);
   }
}
```

Now you can inject like this:

```
class ServiceManager {
    @Inject
    public ServiceManager(Map<String, MyServiceInterface> services) {
        MyServiceInterface service = stacks.get("MyServiceInterface");
        // etc.
    }
}
```

---

Please note when you call `inj.getInstance()` you do have to know the return type of the Object you're trying to create, unless you are planning on doing:

```
Object foo = inj.getInstance(myString);
```

Comment: since the interface is already bound to a specific impl we know which impl class should be used. The challenge for me is to get an instance of the impl when I provide service.interface as a string literal. I am thinking of using a provider that can provide me with a class object in return for a class name which I can use in injector.getInstance. I don't think the MapBinder example fits in this case